# Android DialogFragment to wrap content

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I know that there are similar topics, but I cannot find a working solution for me. The only thing I do is create a DialogFragment, in onCreateView I inflate the xml only with root (image 1080 x 960 in folder xxhdpi and I test on a xxhdpi device) and add this code:

```
private View v;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp_layout, container, false);

    return  v;
}
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.MY_DIALOG);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    return dialog;
}
```

This is the style:

```
    <style name="MY.DIALOG" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/por">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've just decided to test it, because I know that there is a lot of problems with dialog fragments width and height. So my picture doesn't have 1080 pixels width. I tried with full hd pictures and I get the same result - there is a padding/margin on both sides, but only on the left and right side (top and bottom are ok) . Why is that ? How can I fix that?

Comment: I donot understand the question